# Should I rewrite string concat using stringBuilder if I have enough memory?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have following code row:

```
return ROOT_USER_IMAGE_PATH + File.separator + userId 
       + File.separator + nameWithoutExtension + "__" 
       + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmm").format(new Date()) 
       + extension;
```

On code review my colleague said that I replaced it using `StringBuilder`.

I know that it will work faster but I think this enhancement will be absolutely minor and noone can feel it.

What do you think is there meaning to carp with minors like this in modern situation when we have a lot of memory?

Comment: If you've tested it and it works, then making the change suggested by  your colleague is a bit of a waste of time.  However, take it on board that it is better not to write this kind of code in the first place.  Honestly, though, I would have used `String.format( )` to write this - much clearer than a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do nothing. The compiler will make use of a `StringBuilder` for you behind the scenes.

Comment: **nameWithoutExtension** is not final

Comment: That has nothing to do. The compiler will automatically use a `StringBuilder` in the bytecode for concatenating non-literal `String`s.

Comment: Is it actual for java 6 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use `javap -c` on the .class file generated by the compiler and check the usage of `StringBuilder` in the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Your version is already shorter and more readable. Substituting with a `StringBuilder` is not needed, especially that the compiler will most likely optimize it to use a `StringBuilder`.

If you also check the generated bytecode, using `StringBuilder` and `append`ing for each string in your case can result in more bytecode than the simple concatenation.

**Sample bytecode using string concatenation:**

```
aload_1
invokestatic java/lang/String/valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
getstatic java/io/File/separator Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
aload_2
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
```

**Using `StringBuilder`:**

```
invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder/<init>()V
astore_3
aload_3
aload_1
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
pop
aload_3
getstatic java/io/File/separator Ljava/lang/String;
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
pop
aload_3
aload_2
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
pop
aload_3
invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder/toString()Ljava/lang/String;
areturn
```

Usually, it's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` in a loop where some string is being built, or when the string is expected to change by inserting or replacing characters.